# Changing font color based on cell color

Tags: excel, vba, xlsm

I am currently trying to make two buttons to change font color into black or white, based on the cell color being white (blank).

Somehow it does not seem to work at all

```
Sub colorchange()
    Dim Cell As Range
    For Each Cell In Range("AP74:AX80")
        If Cell.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) Then
            Cell.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        End If
    Next Cell
End Sub
```

Comment: so if the cell interior colour is black, you want to change the font colour black as well? (and nothing happens otherwise?)

Comment: If you set the font color the same as the interior color, clearly it will not be visible.

Comment: The interior color is partially white, and i have to make the contents of these white cells appear(Black) or dissappear(White) for certatin circumstances and etc.

Comment: I checked, it works fine. That is, if your intention was to set the font to black for all cells that are black. You mentioned white (or blank, which is a different thing); please note that white is RGB(255.255.255).

Comment: You can use constants for black and white: vbBlack and vbWhite --> then code is much easier to understand as well

Comment: Thank you i kept thinking that 000 was white...

Comment: You can also use `Interior.ColorIndex`; it will have value 1 for black, 2 for white, `xlColorIndexNone` for no fill. That is, assuming you haven't changed the color palette.